# How to aggregate array value objects by key in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework, nosql-aggregation

Given the following collection

```
{ "_id": 1, "items": [ { "k": "A", "v": 1 }, { "k": "B", "v": 2 } ] }
{ "_id": 2, "items": [ { "k": "A", "v": 3 }, { "k": "B", "v": 4 } ] }
```

How can I sum all the items having the same key `k`, preserving the original object format like so:

```
{ "items": [ { "k": "A", "v": 4 }, { "k": "B", "v": 6 } ] }
```

I tried using `$unwind` and `$group`, but it returns a sequence of objects instead of single item.

```
{ $unwind: { path: "$items" } },
{
  $group: {
    _id: "$items.k",
    v: { $sum: "$items.v" }
  }
}
```

I could aggregate it back into the original format, but I feel there must be a better way to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- `$unwind` deconstruct `items` array
- `$group` by `items.k` and get sum of `v`
- `$group` by null and reconstruct `items` array

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  { $unwind: "$items" },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$items.k",
      v: { $sum: "$items.v" }
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: null,
      items: {
        $push: {
          k: "$_id",
          v: "$v"
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/aCYHGOZ7O3Y)

Comment: Thank you turivishal. This also answers my question.
This is the most elegant solution, although I selected the other answer as it gives more flexibility in the aggregation.

Comment: Edit: I marked this answer as correct as it is the recommended solution according to the MongoDB documentation.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a custom [$accumulator](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/accumulator/index.html#accumulator-aggregation) to merge the objects the way you want:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {$project: {
            items: {
                $arrayToObject: "$items"
            }
    }},
    {$group: {
            _id: null,
            items: {
                $accumulator: {
                    init: function(){ return {}; },
                    accumulate: function(obj, doc){
                        Object.keys(doc).forEach(function(k){
                            obj[k] = (obj[k]?obj[k]:0) + doc[k];
                        })
                        return obj;
                    },
                    accumulateArgs: ["$items"],
                    merge: function(obj, doc){
                        Object.keys(doc).forEach(function(k){
                            obj[k] = (obj[k]?obj[k]:0) + doc[k];
                        })
                        return obj;
                    }
                }
            }
    }},
    {$project:{
        _id:0,
        items:{$objectToArray:"$items"}
    }}
])
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer Joe!
I am not able to run this code in Mongodb [playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/AWvVjyeZhXt).
By reading the code I understand that the keys are expected to be in the same order and position in all documents. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: No, but it does assume that all keys will be numeric.  The keys will be matched by name and summed.

Comment: Thanks Joe. Although this solution answers my question, the documentation of [$accomulator](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/accumulator/index.html#accumulator-aggregation) recommends using pipeline operators when possible.

"Executing JavaScript inside of an aggregation operator may decrease performance. Only use the $accumulator operator if the provided pipeline operators cannot fulfill your application’s needs."